# TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters at googleapis

Tags: node.js, google-api, escaping, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm getting a `TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters` with any [`googleapis`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis/) request that contains a extra option like `ValueRenderOption`.
Its ok when i perform a simple request like `/v4/spreadsheets/1DhEUa96iqyQSaj1152jLZFiBH_aaVLOhk-sLEwe30y8/values/Sheet1!A1`

BUT
The request URL is like this: `/v4/spreadsheets/.../values/Sheet1!A1?valueRenderOption=FORMATTED_VALUE`
Give me an error like this:

```
17:34:26 0|application | appending row
17:34:26 0|application | You have triggered an unhandledRejection, you may have forgotten to catch a Promise rejection:
17:34:26 0|application | TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters
17:34:26 0|application | at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:52:11)
17:34:26 0|application | at Object.exports.request (http.js:31:10)
17:34:26 0|application | at Object.exports.request (https.js:199:15)
17:34:26 0|application | at Writable.RedirectableRequest._performRequest (/var/www/www.application.com/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:132:24)
17:34:26 0|application | at Writable.RedirectableRequest (/var/www/www.application.com/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:55:8)
17:34:26 0|application | at Object.wrappedProtocol.request (/var/www/www.application.com/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:269:14)
17:34:26 0|application | at dispatchHttpRequest (/var/www/www.application.com/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:141:25)
17:34:26 0|application | at httpAdapter (/var/www/www.application.com/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:18:10)
17:34:26 0|application | at dispatchRequest (/var/www/www.application.com/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/axios/lib/core/dispatchRequest.js:59:10)
17:34:26 0|application | at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

**Versions tested::: 32.0.0, 28.0.0 and 28.0.1
node version 6.11.1
npm version 3.10.10**